# Access value that was set in Get method in the POST method

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

The problem is simple, but I can't find a solution as I am still new to .net core

I have this code

```
[BindProperty]
    public string Feedback { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<int> IDList { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(string SB, List<int> IDs)
    {
        Feedback = SB;
        IDList = IDs;
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./InviteGroup", new { id = this.IDList });
    }
```

In the Get Method everything is working fine, but in the POST the IDList is empty
Here is my HTML

```
<h2>Feedback</h2>
<form id="frm3" method="post">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.IDList" />
<div>@Html.Raw(Model.Feedback)</div>
```

I tried adding the input hidden but it didn't change anything.
Please help, I have been trying to solve this for 3 Hours now.

Comment: You will need a hidden input for each element in your list.

Comment: Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the values in the Get method, you pass the value as part of your Url. This means that you can access this values in the Post method using the same method as you did in the Get method.

```
[BindProperty]
public string Feedback { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public List<int> IDList { get; set; }

public void OnGet(string SB, List<int> IDs)
{
    Feedback = SB;
    IDList = IDs;
}

public IActionResult OnPost(string SB, List<int> IDs)  
{
    Feedback = SB;
    IDList = IDs;

    return RedirectToPage("./InviteGroup", new { id = this.IDList });
}
```

If you took the values in the Get method then you will get them in Post as well.

Comment: Ok! But is there a way to hide values being passed in the URL, does it pose a security threat ?

Comment: If you pass the information through URL, these information are not safe. If you have sensitive data you have to use https:// and pass the data using a post request but for your question that you pass the data through url you can get these values in both methods (Get and Post).